# How to get building footprint of point within building

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I am using the `osmnx.features.features_from_point` function from OSMNX to get the building footprint of a building using a coordinate tuple that I have received. However, I will have to set the `dist` argument to a certain value that it will return a polygon. I assume that at least one vertex needs to be captured that way.

Now, I have multiple points for multiple buildings and also some smaller buildings (residential) and maybe some bigger buildings (factories, storage places).

Is there a way to avoid setting the distance every single time and rather download the building footprint at the respective coordinate right away using some `within` functionality or so?

I tried playing around with other functions but the from_point function returns the best result so far.